# In C++, is there a difference between 'type name (value)' and 'type name = value' when initializing a variable?

Tags: c++, types, type-conversion, initialization

What is the difference between:

```
type name (value)  //notation and
type name = value  // ?
```

I am currently studying from Bjarne Stroustrup's "Programming: Principles and Practice using C++", and in the fourth chapter he introduces conversion notations.

I have found however that writing `double x (5);` and `double x = 5;` outputs the same result in any occasion. What is the difference between these two? In practice, on the first example, I'm making a conversion, while on the second one I'm making an initialization, but the result is the same.

I have experimented with different values for the variables I'm initializing / converting, but the result was the same.

Comment: Please don't roast i know it sounds very dumb and it's not explained clearly

Comment: There is no difference until you get to class types (and the `explicit` keyword). You can use whichever you prefer until then (and really in most practical situations as well). Both of them are _initialization_ (the first _direct-initialization_ and the second _copy-initialization_) and both do an _implicit conversion from `int` to `double`_ as part of the initialization process in your example.

Comment: If both compile, there's no difference. Some classes are written in a way that bans the second form (`explicit` on the constructor).

Comment: Reopened. The claimed duplicate was much narrower, only about copy construction.

Comment: @PeteBecker Added more accurate duplicates.

Comment: @PeteBecker I have literally no idea what you're talking about. As far as I can tell, the original duplicate target asks *exactly* the same question as this one. Is there any possible answer one could post to this question that would not apply to the original target?

Comment: @cigien — if you add `type value;` before the code in this question you get the original duplicate. That constraint is not present in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the type, it can have different meanings.

Assembly point of view:

1. For int, it is always identical from an assembly point of view for some specific compiler: https://godbolt.org/z/7KTMccr1o
2. For complex types, it can get quite interesting with constructors, copy constructors and move constructors. https://godbolt.org/z/oKdGGTjoo

Counter example of code in C++ where you get different behavior for:

type name(value)

type name = value

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    int a;
public:
    A(int tmp){ a = tmp;};
    ~A(){};
    A(A && tmp){ a = tmp.a+1;};
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const A& a);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const A& a)
{
    os << a.a;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    A a(0);
    A b = 0;
    std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

You also have to use a compiler flag to get different behavior: -fno-elide-constructors.

Comment: Comparing c++ code to assembly doesn't explain things to a beginner who is asking a C++ question not an assembly question.

Comment: Yes you are right, I added a counter example in C++ with custom type. The "smallest" reproducible counter example I could think off in a rush. Hopefully that will help answering.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I don't really understand everything you wrote but i'll get there, eventually

Comment: Great to hear that, I'm certain you will, slowly and steadily the turtle wins the race!